# DeprecationWarning with matplotlib and dateutil

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, python-dateutil

Since i've installed the last version of matplotlib (1.5.1), I have the following error when i try to plot values with `datetime` as X.

> DeprecationWarning: Using both 'count' and 'until' is inconsistent
>   with RFC 2445 and has been deprecated in dateutil. Future versions
>   will raise an error.

Does someone met ths error, and knows how to correct it ?

Answer (score 3):

The issue have been fixed on matplotlib, but not released in a finalised version (>= 1.5.2)

I had to install the current working version with

`pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not an error. It's a warning. 
Second, most likely the problem is not your problem rather a problem in Matplotlib, which need to fix how they call a function or some method form python-dateutil. Most likely, you can ignore this warning, and it will be fixed in the next Matplotlib version.

Comment: This issue is being tracked here https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6155 I would remind you that mpl is maintained by the community, pull requests are always welcome.

Comment: Apparently [the fix was simple](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/6190/files).

Answer (score 1):

Best solution :

in the file `/matplotlib/dates.py`, the line 830 :

`self.rule.set(dtstart=start, until=stop, count=self.MAXTICKS + 1)`

shall be commented